# Can a Default Template Argument correspond to a Specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, partial-specialization

Hi :) I've looked around about this question and there seem to be a lot of related posts, but none of the answers so far could solve my problem. If you know about a post that answers this specific question, please let me know which one and I'll delete this post.

Here is what I'm trying to do; I have a class with one template argument, which default value corresponds to a template specialization. So far (see code below), it doesn't compile. What bugs me is that the similar case with *two* template arguments, and partial template specialization compiles and works fine.. :/

What am I doing wrong?

---

**CASE 1: Two Template Arguments (compiles and works)**

**header**

```
#include <iostream>

struct Special {};

template <class T, class U = Special>
class Bird
{
public:
    inline void operator() () { sing(); }
    inline void sing() const { std::cout << "Piu piu piu" << std::endl; }

private:
    T t; U u;
};

template <class T>
class Bird<T,Special>
{
public:
    inline void operator() () {}

private:
    T t; Special u;
};
```

**cpp**

```
int main()
{
    Bird<double,int> a;
    Bird<double> b;

    a(); b();
}
```

---

**CASE 2: One Template Argument (does not compile)**

**header**

```
#include <iostream>

struct Special {};

template <class U = Special>
class Bird
{
public:
    inline void operator() () { sing(); }
    inline void sing() const { std::cout << "Piu piu piu" << std::endl; }

private:
    U u;
};

template <>
class Bird<Special>
{
public:
    inline void operator() () {}

private:
    Special u;
};
```

**cpp**

```
int main()
{
    Bird<int> a;
    Bird b;

    a(); b();
}
```

I get an error: *missing template arguments before 'b'*. Thanks in advance for taking the time to read this! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Bird` is a *class* template, so you always have to use the angular brackets. Unlike for *function* templates, in case you want to use default template arguments you can omit them, but the angle brackets have to be there:

```
Bird<> b;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, I feel stupid now.. The reason I was doing all this in the first place was to allow "empty templates" for one specific case in my program, but I guess I can't make the code look better than that :( Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Sh3ljohn: Unfortunately you can't :( Good luck with your project :)

Comment: @Sh3ljohn You can always create a typedef like `typedef Bird<> DefaultBird;` or something. Obviously, the typedef will have to have a different name, so, it's not great, but maybe it can work for you.

Comment: @MikaelPersson My "program" is in fact a very small library, so I think it can be confusing for the user if I declare a type with a different name, but thanks a lot for your suggestion!